# Identify short story about two energy beings creating a human out of clay

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, evolution

I hope that you can help me. Around 10 + years ago my wife and I were staying at Bernardus Lodge in CA. Every night 3 or 4 very small booklets would be delivered to our room. One of the booklets contained a very short story written by one of the “big guys of science fiction” . The story has haunted me for years and I would love to re-read it. The story line is as follows:

> Two beings who started out as possible humans who evolved (over billions of years) into some sort of  energy with unbelievable powers ended up on earth and were making a human out of clay- just prior to it being completed one of the energy “beings” smashed the clay so that it wouldn't become man.  I never have forgotten this story and I would only love to read it again and again.

The story was maybe 3 pages long – hope that you can help  me.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188226/very-short-story-two-sentient-clouds-converse-one-remembers-being-a-human (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 17):

That is ["Eyes Do More Than See"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyes_Do_More_Than_See) by Isaac Asimov, originally written for *Playboy*, but rejected and so published in *F&SF* in 1965.

[image: Fantasy and Science Fiction - April 1965]

Comment: Complete version available here; http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~tolis/toli/other/eyes.html

Comment: Paper? Like they use in the toilet?