# Very short story: two sentient clouds converse; one remembers being a human

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read in an old sci-fi anthology a very short story, about two sentient clouds/jets of energy having a conversation and one of them eventually remembering it used to be a human being. The story was about 2 pages long and from an anthology from around the 50's if I had to guess.

Any idea on the name of the story?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to understand how this site works. From the sound of things, you may have given us as much info as you can about this short story; that said, you may want to see the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for tips on additional things you might remember, and could edit into your question.

Comment: Not merely human, specifically a woman.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is most likely [“Eyes Do More Than See”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyes_Do_More_Than_See) by Isaac Asimov.

> In the very distant future — about a trillion years in the future —
>   humans have long since abandoned physical form. They exist as energy
>   entities spanning space.
>
> Two of these entities, known only as Ames and Brock, tire of artistic
>   competitions using manipulations of energy. They discuss a new project
>   in which they attempt to manipulate physical matter, and Ames creates
>   a sculpture of a human head. Brock, who was once a woman, is painfully
>   reminded of her physical past and that she once knew love. She adds
>   tears to the head and then flees. Ames remembers that he had once been
>   a man, and the force of his vortex splits the head as he turns in
>   search of Brock.

Comment: Full text is available on [the Internet archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v028n04_1965-04_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v028n04_1965-04_PDF#page/n113/mode/2up).

Comment: Oh my, that was spot on! thanks a bunch!