# Short story (Asimov?) involving incorporeal beings working on how to manipulate matter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story where two incorporeal beings meet, and one shows the other something they've been working on: the ability to manipulate matter. At the end of the story,

> the character builds a replica of a human being, and it becomes clear the characters themselves were once human.

I thought this one was an Asimov, but my searching has proven fruitless so it's probably a completely different author.

Comment: Most likely answered by [Very short story: two sentient clouds converse; one remembers being a human](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188226/98028). If you confirm, we can close the question as a duplicate for bookkeeping reasons, as is [the policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028) on this stack :)

Comment: That's the one! Thank you, Jenayah!

Comment: You're welcome! :)